# NgShow dois parâmetros - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Olá tudo bem? Espero que sim! Ainda sou meio *noob* no angular e hoje me deparei com uma dúvidas, preciso passar duas expression no ng-show do angularjs, preciso que o mesmo faça o show ou hide e seta uma var do *$scope* para '*null*', exemplo que tentei:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group" ng-show="!objParametros.tipo; objParametros.status=''">
    <p>teste</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Na tag do elemento a ser mostrado ou ocultado, repita para cada lógica um ng-show.
<tr ng-show="{{propostas.id_votacao_andamento}} <= 0" ng-show="{{propostas.id_votacao_concluida}} <= 0"
>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá tudo certo? Uma dica que pode ajuda é a seguinte:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group" ng-show="isShowSetNull()">
    <p>teste</p>
</div>

<script>
    function isShowSetNull(){
         if (!objParametros.tipo){
             objParametros.status = null;
             return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
</script>
```

A ideia é a seguinte, você deixa no controlador da View a responsabilidade de exibir e alterar o valor, e chama a função na sua View, acredito que assim fique mais simples de evoluir o código. Lembrando que o ng-show espera um boolean como entrada!

OBS: Coloquei entre a tag script pra fazer sentido, mas a ideia é deixar o script dentro do controlador.

Answer (score 1):

O `ng-show` espera um valor booleano, ou seja, `true` ou `false` então você deve tratá-lo como uma expressão lógica:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group" ng-show="!objParametros.tipo || objParametros.status=''">
    <p>teste</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Não irá funcionar como desejado, pois quando a primeira condição for verdadeira a variável não será preenchida. O que ele quer é que exibindo ou mostrando o componente a variavel seja setada como vazio.

Comment: Então além de fazer o ng-show terá que fazer um on-click para uma função

Comment: Outro jeito seria criar um método que retorna bool e seta a variavel. Mais é importante lembrar que isso pode impactar em empilhamento de memória no DOM, visto que o two-way-databinding do AngularJs empilha watches na memória para fazer o o trabalho sujo. O melhor seria utilizar um evento na alteração do objParametros.tipo para setar a variável.